# create copy of google file in the same drive directory

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm looking for a way to create a copy of a given file in the same Google Drive directory using Google Apps Script.
The goal is to iterate through a folder structure looking for files owned by a specific user; when such a file is found [doc, spreadsheet, PDF], create a copy in the same place and delete the original.

The reason for this is that we have files owned by users in other domains and Google currently does not allows the transfer of ownership outside the domain. Using a script like this, could help us solve the problem.

Any ideas?
Thanks,

Comment: What have you tried already? It's 100% possible without special tricks, provided you have the permission to use `File#makeCopy()` and `File#setTrashed(bool)` on the source file. Note that if you're iterating a large structure you're going to need to set up a "resumable" script structure to combat the 6min execution limit - plenty of examples of that here on SO.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your response. I actually haven't tried anything just yet; I was actually looking for ideas on how to approach this problem. I can see that those methods will help me with the creation of the copy and the deletion of the original.